# This loop isn't running correctly

Tags: php

I'm trying to print this array and he's getting some error. I need a different pair of eyes to see what's wrong with this!

```
<?php foreach($articles as $article) { ?>
<div>
    <div class="parent-info">
        <div class="parent-info-header">

<?php echo "<h2>" . $article->title . "</h2>"; ?>

        </div>

<?php echo "<p class=\"parent-info-text\">" . $article->body . "</p>" ; ?>

    </div>
</div>
} ?>
```

Comment: You forgot to put `<?php ` in front of the last line.

Comment: As obvious as the problem may be, saying "getting some error" is not a good way to describe what is going on.

Comment: 'some error' is not helpful. If you're getting an error message, post it.

Comment: Mike, I'm using CI, and I'm new to CI and PHP. I can't seem to find a good log that indicates me what type of error it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php foreach($articles as $article) { ?>
<div>
    <div class="parent-info">
        <div class="parent-info-header">

<?php echo "<h2>" . $article->title . "</h2>"; ?>

        </div>

<?php echo "<p class=\"parent-info-text\">" . $article->body . "</p>" ; ?>

    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?> <!-- You forgot the <?php tag here!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($articles as $article): ?>
    <div>
        <div class="parent-info">
           <div class="parent-info-header">
               <h2><?= htmlspecialchars($article->title) ?></h2>
           </div>
           <p class="parent-info-text"><?= htmlspecialchars($article->body) ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Use more readable php within your html.. it will save your life!  Also, it's always smart to wrap any content being echoed into html with htmlspecialchars, so I've added that as well.

The short echo requires the short_open_tag to be enabled in your php.ini, so I'm not entirely correct in recommending its use.

Comment: Hey, can you point me to the documentation for the "<?=" syntax?

Comment: @KHMKShore [echo also has a shortcut syntax, where you can immediately follow the opening tag with an equals sign. Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this short syntax only works with the short_open_tag configuration setting enabled.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Answer (score 0):

Protip:

```
$frame = <<<_EOI_
<div>
    <div class="parent-info">
        <div class="parent-info-header">
            <h2>%s</h2>
        </div>
        <p class="parent-info-text">%s</p>
    </div>
</div>
_EOI_;

foreach($articles as $article) {
    printf($frame, $article->title, $article->body)
}
```

Learning [`printf()`/`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) makes things *MUCH* more readable/manageable. Also, [Heredocs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php foreach($articles as $article) { ?>
<div>
    <div class="parent-info">
        <div class="parent-info-header">

<?php echo "<h2>" . $article->title . "</h2>"; ?>

        </div>

<?php echo '<p class="parent-info-text">' . $article->body . '</p>' ; ?>

    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```